# Why do primitive array fields print out null pointer exceptions?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

```
public class Whatever {
    static double d;
    static char c;
    static String[] s;
    static char[] b;
    static double[] dd;
    static Whatever w;
    static Whatever[] ww;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Whatever.d); //prints out 0.0
        System.out.println("hi"+Whatever.c+"hi"); //prints out hi hi
        System.out.println(s); //prints out null
        System.out.println(b); //null pointer exception!
        System.out.println(Whatever.dd);
        System.out.println(Whatever.w);
        System.out.println(Whatever.ww);
    }
}
```

Why do I get a null pointer exception?

Please explain in terms of memory if you can, however I have a basic understanding of memory so don't get too in depth either.

Comment: Post your real code. What you have now is uncompilable.

Comment: Are you sure this code is compiling fine as x doesn't seem to be declared as static?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the keyword static when declaring the array.

Comment: Okay I'll post the real code, sorry I was trying to shorten it to make it more readable.  One second.

Comment: @KacyRaye Thanks for trying to simplify your code to make your question more understandable. Remember that when you do so, you need to make sure that the code exactly reproduces the problem you are asking about and does not introduce other, unrelated problems.

Comment: I don't see how this code could throw an NPE. Which line is throwing it?

Comment: @Bohemian I just ran it and I do get a NPE at line `System.out.println(b);`. When that line is commented out it runs as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now that you've posted your full code its easier to help! This is *normally* what happens when you invoke `PrintStream.println` with a primitive array:

```
String s = String.valueOf(x);
```

Which eventually does this:

```
return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
```

As you can see, the possibility of the supplied object being null is explicitly handled. However, there is a specific overload on the `PrintStream` class, *just* for char arrays. Here is a rough trace of the logic:

```
write(cbuf, 0, cbuf.length);
```

Where `cbuf` is the given char array. As you can see, it tries to reference the character arrays length, which will blow up with an NPE if the array is not initialized. It's an odd and unfortunate inconsistency in the implementation.

So now you understand *why* the NPE is occurring - to fix it simply initialize the char array before trying to print it out.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah I just went through this question with a tutor at my school and we managed to find that method just for the char arrays.
We came to the conclusion that it had something to do with the method but you explained it more in depth so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems here:

```
1. You're not allocating any space for `int x`
2. If you want to print the contents of `x`, it should be `x.toString()`
3. What did you expect the output to be from your sample code?
```

I'm guessing #3 isn't what you're actually working with, I would suggest you show your real code to get a real answer :)

Hopefully this can clear it up a bit for you.

```
$ cat Whatever.java 
public class Whatever {
    static final int MAX = 5;
    int[] x = new int[MAX]; // allocate array to sizeof '5'

    public Whatever() {
        // do stuff
    }

    public void addStuff() {
        for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
            x[i] = i + 2;

    }

    public void printX() {
        for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
            System.out.println(i + ": " + x[i]);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Whatever w = new Whatever();  // new instance of 'Whatever'
        w.addStuff();                 // add some ints to the array
        w.printX();                   // print out the array
        // print the Array 'x'
        System.out.println("Array: " + w.x);
    }
}
$ java Whatever 
0:  2
1:  3
2:  4
3:  5
4:  6
Array: [I@870114c
```

Comment: He is not trying to print the address of anything. The default `toString()` method is called which return a string representation of the object. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

Answer (score 0):

The problem is basically rooted in how `PrintStream.println(...)` is implemented. Except for `char[]`, a primitive array is treated as a `java.lang.Object`. So the `println` overload used is [`println(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29). Underneath, printing an object involves calling the object's `toString()`. Hence the NPE.

If you want to be defensive of nulls, you should consider using [`String.valueOf(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: `String.valueOf()` also throws NPE for char arrays that are not initialized. If I am not mistaken it is because `valueOf(char[])` calls the constructor `String(char[])` which then tries to use the length of the array.

Comment: You're right -- my answer is only partially complete. It only explains the behavior for the non `char[]` arrays.